# How to use HTML5 Web Audio API to record my voice

Tags: html, three.js, html5-audio, tquery

I'm looking for a way to record my voice and - according to the recorded voice - move an animation towards left or right.

I heard HTML5 has an Audio API through which you can record your voice, but I have no idea how to do that.

I will be thankful to everyone who can help me or come up with some solutions, suggestions, code or guidelines to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on webkit-browsers you can use the [get user media api](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html) with `webkitGetUserMedia` - like demonstrated on [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/#toc-webaudio-api).
if you want to use your voice to create javascript events (e.g. to control objects on the screen) you would have to analyze the incoming sound (e.g. high frequency for event1 - low frequency for event2, speech analysis is much more complicated, see below)

alternatively, there is chrome's 'x-webkit-speech' speech recognition, (see an example [here](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#speech-input)), which will analyze speech on google's servers and is therefore probably too slow for real-time control.

I don't know of any real-time speech analysis *in the browser*, but would be happy to find a (even very basic) possibility.

edit: adds some code (adapted from [here](http://www.phpied.com/x-webkit-speech-input-and-textareas/))

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head
  <body>
    <input type="search" id="mike" x-webkit-speech>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var mike = document.getElementById('mike');
      mike.onwebkitspeechchange = function(e) {
        console.log(e); // SpeechInputEvent
        console.log(e.results[0].utterance);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for a good suggestion. I'll try to work with it but just wanted to confirm is there any possibility that i can record my voice through 'x-webkit-speach' and can utilize it to move my animation. Is there any code or example which i can refer.